# How could Ant-Man become so small?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man

In Marvel's movie *Ant-Man*, Scott can become small by reducing the space in atoms.

So he surely can't get smaller than atoms. But in a scene in the movie, Scott gets very smaller, even smaller than atom. Isn't it an exaggeration of his powers?

Comment: It’s comic book physics. Best not to over think it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There is a lot of empty space in atoms.](https://education.jlab.org/qa/how-much-of-an-atom-is-empty-space.html)

The structure of an atom is somewhat similar to the structure of our solar system.  In this picture, an the atom is on the top, and the solar system is on the bottom.

[image]

But the diagram of the atom, and the diagram of the solar system, are both huge exaggerations. If the whole earth was the size of a map pin (a little smaller than a pea), the sun would be almost 100 feet away. And there are more planets that are much farther from the sun! So there is **a lot of empty space** in the solar system, and also a lot of empty space in an atom.

The *Ant-Man* technology says that it is "getting rid of the space in atoms".  There is plenty of space in an atom to compress.  And if you compress all the atoms in a human that much, you can make a person smaller than an atom.

Comment: I gace done some googling and sone calculation and I've found out that a man would still be bigger than atom if the space is squeezed. So it is illogical that Scott shirnked and became smaller than an atom.

Comment: @AsifIqubal Darn. I wonder if the space _between_ atoms is compressed as well? There's a whole lot of space there, too!

Comment: Even if you do that,it would not still be enough.

Answer (score 2):

#### No, it's not an exaggeration.

Ant-Man (Scott Lang) shrinking powers can go way bellow the atomic size:

> Scott Lang **can also shrink to sub-microscopic size**, and thereby enter the countless "subatomic universes".
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_(Scott_Lang)#Powers_and_abilities)</sup>

In the movie, Hank Pym equipped the Ant-Man suit with a regulator so that it won't get into the sub-atomic quantum realm and get lost forever, like his wife (van Dyne's mother) did:

> While van Dyne harbors resentment towards Pym about her mother Janet's death, he reveals that Janet, known as the Wasp, disappeared into a subatomic quantum realm while disabling a Soviet nuclear missile. Pym warns Lang that **he could suffer a similar fate if he overrides his suit's regulator**.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_(film)#Plot)</sup>

Comment: But his suit's power is that it can reduce the space between atoms. So how can he be smaller than atom by reducing the space between atom? This seems out of logic to me.

Comment: @AsifIqubal He reduces the space **in** atoms not the space **between** atoms. There is plenty of scope for getting smaller than an atom if you do that (and it is comic physics so we shouldn't argue too much).

Answer (score 1):

Ant-Man can go beyond reducing the space in atoms, he can go subatomic level which Hank Pym suggested him not to go:

> **Hank Pym:** Do not screw with the regulator. If that regulator is
>   compromised you would go sub-atomic.
>
> **Scott Lang:** What does that mean?
>
> **Hank Pym:** It means that you would enter a quantum realm.
>
> **Scott Lang:** What does that mean?
>
> **Hank Pym:** It means that you would enter a reality where all concepts
>   of time and space become irrelevant as you shrink for all eternity.
>   Everything that you know, and love, gone forever.
>
> **Scott Lang:** Cool. Yeah. I'm... If it ain't broke... - [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478970/quotes/qt2757301?mavIsAdult=false)

So going beyond atom was possible from start but not suggested to do so because you can get lost like Hank Pym's wife did.